# How to enable security features for my document in Latex

Tags: pdf, viewers

I want to know if it is possible to impose security features on my document such as locking editing, printing, commenting, copying, etc in Latex. Is there any way to do this in Latex or do I need an external pdf editor like Adobe Acrobat?

Comment: There are no security features in PDF, unless you use full encryption (i.e. you need a password to open). Everything else is just a suggestion to compliant PDF readers (which my reader of choice, e.g., will happily ignore.) Of course you can still annoy some less tech-savvy users, if you really must.

Comment: Thank you very much @Ingmar. I now know that the only security feature that is effective is encrypting the document with a password.